# The Emacs eww doesn't load the YouTube

Tags: emacs, eww

When I type the command `eww` and enter the url google.com it just loads the front page of Google nicely just the way it should be loaded.
But when i search for YouTube on this Google front page and hit search, a new buffer starts but nothing gets loaded on it. Just nothing.
Only the cursor remains still at the beginning of the buffer for the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is also your question?

https://old.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/vc3zxs/the_eww_doesnt_display_my_html_file_like_it/

Both questions can be answered thus:

`eww` is *not* a fully-featured web browser.  Not by a long shot.  It handles much of the basic markup, which is entirely sufficient in *certain* cases; but it is absolutely not a full replacement for the likes of Firefox as far as the web *in general* is concerned.

Of particular note<sup>1</sup>:

- Stylesheets are not supported (which seems relevant to the other question).
- Javascript is not supported (which is relevant to this question).

That all said, there is experimental work for handling `<video>` elements in eww if you have built Emacs from the master branch with xwidget support.  See https://lars.ingebrigtsen.no/2021/11/09/finally-videos-in-eww/ for more.  This will (probably) be included in Emacs 29.

---

<sup>1</sup> In an ideal world, most web sites would function acceptably in the absence of both these things.  In reality, that's not even close to accurate.  The web developers who care about users without javascript have been on the losing side of that battle for about 15 years, and it's only getting worse as time goes on.

On the positive side, I think the CSS situation is actually *improving* slightly on account of the Accessibility requirements which various governments have introduced in recent years, as these requirements always have "use correct semantic markup" at their core.  That still doesn't help you when a lack of javascript results in a blank page, but it's something...